# Solo se ejecuta la sentencia de la suma

Tags: php, html

1. **
2. ```
   <head> 

   <title></title> 

   </head> 

   <body> 

   <h2>Operaciones  basicas </h2> 
   <form action="basic.php" method="post">

   1 suma<input type="hidden" name="1"></input>
   <p>  2 resta<input type="hidden"  name="2"></input>
   <p>  3 Producto <input type="hidden" name="3"></input>
   <p>  4 Division <input type="hidden" name="4"></input> 
   <p>  5 Residuo <input type="hidden" name="5"></input>
   <p>  Opcion <input type="text" name="select" size="8"></input>
   <p>  Numero 1<input type="text" name="num1" size="8"></input>
   <p>  Numero 2<input type="text" name="num2" size="8"></input>
   <p>  <input type="submit" name="calcular" value="Enviar"></input>  
   <input type="reset" name="limpiar" value="Borrar"></input> 

   </form> 

   <?php 

   $suma=1; $resta=2;

   $producto=3; $division=4; $residuo=5;

    if(isset($_REQUEST['calcular'])) { 

                   $valor1=$_REQUEST['num1']; 
                   $valor2=$_REQUEST['num2'];  
                   $suma=$_REQUEST['1']; >
                   $resta=$_REQUEST['2']; 
                   $producto=$_REQUEST['3']; >
                   $division=$_REQUEST['4'];  
                  $rediduo=$_REQUEST['5']; 
        if($suma=1){
             $suma=$valor1+$valor2; echo "La suma es $suma"; 
        }elseif($resta=2){
             $resta=$valor1-$valor2; echo "El resultado de la resta es $resta";
        }elseif($producto=3){ 
             $producto=$valor1*$valor2; echo "El resultado del producto es  $producto"; 
   } elseif($division=4){

        $division=$valor1/$valor2;  echo "El resultado de la division es                 $division"; 
   }  elseif($residuo=5){ 

   $residuo=$valor1%$valor2; echo "El residuo > es $residuo"; 
   } 
   } ?>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

**

---

Comment: estimada tiene que explicar un poco más el código para que la gente de la comunidad pueda entender bien tu pregunta

Comment: Hola buenas tarde  y bienvenida a stackoverflow, por favor si puede explica mejor tu pregunta para poderte ayudar. ya que así como esta es muy amplia y no queda claro lo que preguntas. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

tienes que contarnos mas sobre tu problema, te paso un ejemplo

index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Operadores Aritm&eacute;meticos</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Calculadora</h1>
  <form action="resul.php" method="post">
   <select name="operador">
    <option value="suma">Suma</option>
    <option value="resta">Resta</option>
    <option value="multiplicacion">Producto</option>
    <option value="division">Divisi&oacute;n</option>
                <option value="residuo">Residuo</option>
   </select><p />
   Ingresa tu primer n&uacute;mero:<br />
   <input type="text" name="valor1"><br />
   Ingresa tu segundo valor:<br />
            <input type="text" name="valor2"><p>
            
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
   <input type="reset" value="Borrar">
   
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

resul.php

```html
<?php 
 if ($_POST ["valor1"] !="" and $_POST ["valor2"]!=""){
  if ($_POST["operador"] == "suma") {
   print ($resultado = $_POST ["valor1"] + $_POST ["valor2"]);
   print ('<br /><a href="index.php">Regresar</a>');
  } elseif ($_POST["operador"] == "resta") {
   print ($resultado = $_POST ["valor1"] - $_POST ["valor2"]);
   print ('<br /><a href="index.php">Regresar</a>');
  } elseif ($_POST["operador"] == "multiplicacion") {
   print ($resultado = $_POST ["valor1"] * $_POST ["valor2"]);
   print ('<br /><a href="index.php">Regresar</a>');
  } elseif ($_POST["operador"] == "division") {
   print ($resultado = $_POST ["valor1"] / $_POST ["valor2"]);
   print ('<br /><a href="index.php">Regresar</a>');
  } elseif ($_POST["operador"] == "residuo") {
   print ($resultado = $_POST ["valor1"] * $_POST ["valor2"]) / 100;
   print ('<br /><a href="index.php">Regresar</a>');
  }
 } else {
  print("Ingresa alg&uacute;n valor");
  print ('<br /><a href="index.php">regresar</a>');
 }
?>
```